# Putting Video on Webpage

Tags: html, audio, video, flash

I am making a *very* simple website, which should have nothing more than a video on it called "starenders.swf". The problem is, it will not show! Here is the code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Starenders</TITLE>
<STYLE>
body, td, p {font-size: 12pt; font-family: times new roman, times, serif}
h1 {font-weight: normal; font-size: 26pt; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif}
h2 {font-weight: normal; font-size: 18pt; font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif}
h3 {font-weight: normal; font-size: 16pt}
h4 {font-weight: normal; font-size: 14pt}
a {text-decoration: none}
a:hover {text-decoration: underline}
</STYLE>
<META id=skype_v3_tb_marker_id name=SKYPE_PARSING_HAS_FINISHED content=metacontent>
</HEAD>
<BODY style="MARGIN: 10px 10px; BACKGROUND: #ffffff" text=#000000>&nbsp;
<DIV style="BACKGROUND: #000000" align=center><EMBED height=100% type=application/x-shockwave-flash width=100% src=starenders.swf originalWidth="100%" originalHeight="100%" quality="high" allowNetworking="internal" allowScriptAccess="never" allowFullScreen="true" play="true" loop="true" ></DIV></BODY>
```

When I launch the webpage, it does not work

HERE IS THE WEBSITE: 
http://starenders.github.io/

Thanks!

[George](http://georgeocodes.github.io)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML 5 offers a special video tag . The code you can use should be -

```
<video type="video/swf" controls >

 <source type="video/swf" src="The source of the video should be here ." />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the browser don't have the flash player plugin, then will not load swf file. For that you just need to install the plugin. And also check whether the file is uploaded properly.

```
<EMBED height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width=100% src="http://starenders.github.io/starenders.swf" originalWidth="100%" originalHeight="100%" quality="high" allowNetworking="internal" allowScriptAccess="never" allowFullScreen="true" play="true" loop="true" >
```

Comment: Sorry- made a mistake in code. Its not http://starenders.github.io/starenders.swf  , its just starenders.swf.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not playing, even on browsers which have flash installed, is that the server is reporting it cannot find the file - see screen shot from a browser console:

[image]

Often this is just a path issue on your server - i.e. the file does exist but the path the server is using to look for videos does not match the path the video is actually located at.

**Update:**

The web page you provide in the link above includes a flash embed tag with the src set as "src=starenders.swf". The error that the browser is reporting in the browser console indicates that the server is responding with a message that it cannot find this resource. Assuming the file name is correct and that it does actually exist on the server, then it is most likely that the file 'starenders.swf' is in a location that the server does not expect to look for video files in (this will depend on your server and it's configuration).

As an aside if you going to use a HTML5 video tag, which is certainly a good suggestion, then you could consider using a non 'swf' video, which may allow you reach a wider audience - for info on different video formats supported by different browsers and devices see here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: Sorry- made a mistake in code. Its not http://starenders.github.io/starenders.swf  , its just starenders.swf.

Comment: @GeorgeOCodes - this error will be the same regardless of whether you use an embedded flash object or the HTML5 video tag - both are valid approaches.